# When are dachshunds' nails unhealthily long?

Tags: dogs, health, grooming

This dachshund's nails are cut every 2 months by a professional. Allegedly it is going to be taken to a session in a matter of days. Its owner is very confident that there there is no 'nail problem' whatsoever; 'this is a digger type dog'. It is kept ~23h25min of a day indoors, 10-17 minutes a day is the usual time that is spent walking on concrete or rocky surface.

Here are a couple of pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So do you think that the nails are way too long and should have been cut a month ago? The consensus on the internet as I've seen is that dachshunds' nails should be cut every 2-3 weeks and that their nails should not touch the ground, especially not make clicking noises. (Clicking noises are heard for a month or so...) May there be health problems in the future, or may there be already?

*I'd appreciate if you'd mention where where your experience/expertise from.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, those nails are too long.

[image]

This example is how nails should look after you cut, if the nails grow past the paw pad then they are too long. Some dogs have long quicks which make it much more difficult to maintain at a shorter level.

Nails should be trimmed at least once a month, sometimes every 3 weeks. Exercise on pavement or sidewalks is great for naturally filing down nails (back feet especially).

Overgrown nails can be painful, it also changes the animals gait which can cause issues down the road. It is especially hard on our old arthritic pets.